# Linking an ActionScript file with a Flash file?

Tags: flash, actionscript, linker, include, require

How does one link an AS file with a flash file? Similar to the include or require in php.

Answer (score 0):

You used to have to put a Hash tag in the call such as: `#include "yourfile.as"` in AS2, but in AS3 it is simply `include "yourfile.as"`

Comment: I have a flash file with multiple layers. Do I have to write inclue "yourfile.as" in all of the layers or in only one of them?